# CTabView syncronize after removeview

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have been struggling with a problem for weeks. I have an MDI app, explore style. In right side, I have a CTabView, which has 5 CListViews and one CFormView. Depending on what I choose in leftview (CTreeView), I should remove (or add) the FormView from CTabView.

The CTabView could be re-arranged by drag and drop (you could drag CTestFormView as first tab), and they are stored in that order.

Here is the link to have a sample project that simulates the problem:

[Explore sample project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtSPCxnvttzegUgfy38YOx23__Ll)

In left view, I have:

[image]

As soon as I select "Without test-form-view" item, the CTestFormView is removed from CTabView, using CTabView::RemoveView.

To reproduce that, you can do the following simple steps:

1. Go to "With test-form-view"
2. Drag CTestFormView as first tab
   [image]
3. Select, let's say, CExploreListView4

[image]

4. Select "Without test-form-view" item in left view
   [image]

The "CTestFormView" has disappeared from CTabView, and the first tab is selected. Right-click on this CExploreListView1, and you will see the context menu of CExploreListView**4**, not the context menu of CExploreListView**1**.

If you select another treeitem from leftview ("With-test-form-view"), which add CTestFormView, then all listviews from CTabView are not redrawn correctly. Is there a bug in CTabView ?

With this following code I remove a view in CTabView:

```
RemoveView(nTabIndex);
```

This is the code I used to add a view to CTabView dynamically:

```
int CExploreTabbedView::AddView(CRuntimeClass* pViewClass, const CString& strViewLabel, int iIndex /*= -1*/, CCreateContext* pContext/* = NULL*/, BOOL bAfterCreation/* = FALSE*/)
{
ASSERT_VALID(this);
ENSURE(pViewClass != NULL);
ENSURE(pViewClass->IsDerivedFrom(RUNTIME_CLASS(CView)));

CView* pView = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CView, pViewClass->CreateObject());
ASSERT_VALID(pView);

if(! pView->Create(NULL, _T(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), &m_wndTabs, (UINT)-1, pContext))
{
    TRACE1(_T("CTabView:Failed to create view '%s'\n"), pViewClass->m_lpszClassName);
    return -1;
}

CDocument* pDoc = GetDocument();
if (pDoc != NULL)
{
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);

    BOOL bFound = FALSE;
    for (POSITION pos = pDoc->GetFirstViewPosition();! bFound && pos != NULL;)
    {
        if(pDoc->GetNextView(pos) == pView)
            bFound = TRUE;
    }
    if(! bFound)
        pDoc->AddView(pView);
}

pView->SetParent(this);

if(bAfterCreation)
    pView->SendMessage(WM_INITIALUPDATE, 0, 0);

m_wndTabs.InsertTab(pView, strViewLabel, iIndex);

int nTabs = m_wndTabs.GetTabsNum();
return nTabs - 1;
}
```

Could you help me figure out why removing/adding view to CTabView is causing this problem?

Comment: Since you are struggling with MFC for **months** now, had you considered actually reading a book? Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1572316950) is a fine resource.

Comment: I would, if this would help me in this case ... but it would help me ? This a concretely case ...

Comment: I guess add/removing tab it is not the right approach, but CMFCTabCtrl::ShowTab (show or hide), which save a lot of issues compared with first approach.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the context where you add the view and set the document there.
Like:

```
    CCreateContext newContext;
    newContext.m_pNewViewClass = NULL;
    newContext.m_pNewDocTemplate = NULL;
    newContext.m_pLastView = NULL;
    newContext.m_pCurrentFrame = NULL;
    newContext.m_pCurrentDoc =  GetDocument();
    CTabView *pTab = GetLayoutViewsTab();
    int index=pTab->AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(YourClass), tabName,-1,&newContext);
```